# Examples of algebraic closures of finite index

Tags: fields, ac.commutative-algebra

So there are easy examples for algebraic closures that have index two and infinite index: $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and the algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$. What about the other indices?

EDIT: Of course $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} \neq \mathbb{C}$. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: I bet you were not expecting the answer to be a theorem.  It's one of the coolest little theorems in all of Galois theory.

Comment: Incidentally, C is not an algebraic closure of Q, since it contains transcendental elements like e (or more generally, because it has uncountable cardinality).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Theorem (Artin-Schreier, 1927): Let K be an algebraically closed field and F a proper subfield of K with $[K:F] < \infty$.  Then F is real-closed and $K = F(\sqrt{-1})$.

See e.g. Jacobson, Basic Algebra II, Theorem 11.14.

Comment: Sure, you put LaTeX in your answer, but I answered first! =)

Comment: @Harry: You beat him by three and a half minutes only. That is about the time it would take Pete to type in his answer plus look up the exact reference in Jacobson's book. A clear case of independent responses if I ever saw one.

Comment: I know that!  I just typed it out as fast as possible because I knew the answer and so did everyone else.  I wasn't claiming he copied it, I was claiming, "FIRST POST!!!"

Comment: Original reference, for the record: Emil Artin und Otto Schreier: _Eine Kennzeichnung der reell abgeschlossenen Körper_,  Abhandlungen aus dem Mathematischen Seminar der Universität Hamburg **5** #1 (1927) 225–231 (doi:10.1007/BF02952522). Quoth Zentralblatt: “In Ergänzung der Untersuchungen über die algebraische Konstruktion reeller Körper der Verf. (ibidem 5 (1926), 85-99; F. d.M. 52) wird bewiesen, dass die reell abgeschlossenen Körper identisch sind mit den Körpern, die durch endliche Erweiterung algebraisch abgeschlossen werden können, ohne selbst algebraisch abgeschlossen zu sein.’

Comment: I wish I could upvote your original reference. I love digging up old German math articles.

Comment: Am I the only person who finds this kind of competition to be an unhealthy expenditure of effort?

Comment: @Boris: You are not. 

Answer (score 29):

The Artin-Schreier theorem says that every algebraic closure of finite index has index 2, and it's the algebraic closure of a real-closed field.

Page 299 of Algebra by Serge Lang.  [Google Books Link](http://books.google.com/books?id=Fge-BwqhqIYC&lpg=PP1&ots=IKy9T7D7C2&dq=algebra%20serge%20lang&pg=PA299#v=onepage&q=&f=false)  to the page.