# Is there a subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{R}$ is a finite algebraic extension of $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, fields, galois-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Examples of algebraic closures of finite index](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8756/examples-of-algebraic-closures-of-finite-index)

The question is in the title. 
I can prove that if such field $F$ exist then the extension $\mathbb{R}/F$ cannot be of degree $2$ (essentially because there are no automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$ and an extension of degree 2 would create one)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the degree of $\mathbf R$ over $F$ were $d$, then the degree of $\mathbf C$ over $F$ would be $2d$, contradicting the [Artin-Schreier theorem](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf).